# How can I navigate to my html file from App.js file in same tab?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, navigation

I am working on react project. I want to navigate to my HTML file from App.js without opening a new tab.ie it should open on same tab of browser

My HTML file (map.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Opens New tab</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You came here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <a target="_blank" href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "map.html"}>
                    {" "}
                    Map
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Now I am navigating by doing this in App.js

`<a target="_blank" href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "map.html"} > Map</a>`

I want to navigate to my HTML page without opening the new tab and also would like a way to know how can I navigate back to previous page without clicking back button of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `target="_blank"` attribute from the `<a>` element.

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "map.html"}>
                    {" "}
                    Map
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks..Can you suggest  a way to go back to App.js without hitting on back button..?

Comment: You can use the JavaScript function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to route to map.html onclick
then you are doing in wrong way
you can use react-router-dom

instead of creating map.html you should create map.js in src folder
and import it to App.js

for routing in react recommended way is react routing

map.js (instead of map.html)

```js
import React from "react";

const Map = () =>{
 return <p>You came here</p>
}

export default Map;
```

you don't have to write head tags and other everywhere

now in App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Map from "./map"; //this is map.js

const App = () =>{
 return <Map/>
}

export default App;
```

this is without routing...
now with routing
in App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Map from "./map"; //this is map.js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () =>{
 return(
<>
<Link to="/map">Map</Link>

<Router>
<Switch>
<Route path="/map" component={<Map>}/>
</Switch>
</Router>
</>
    )
}

export default App;
```

when you will click on map it we show content of map.js page in same tab

Note: react-router-dom used here is version 5 latest is version 6. read reactjs official documentation.